# How do we manage granular changesets in the central/shared repository?

Tags: mercurial, workflow, dvcs

I've used Mercurial for years locally, but now we are doing a pilot of switching over from Subversion at my company.

We're embracing the fact that developers will now be making more granular changesets--some of which may not even build. When developers push their changes to the central repository, all of these changesets will show up in the history - this is natural and expected.

My question is: how do we deal with the fact that, because changesets are more granular, this makes it possible for developers to update to a revision that doesn't build? We are coming from a world where you can checkout anywhere in the repository and reasonably expect to be able to make a release from that point. With DVCS's, how do you tell where a "safe" revision is?

This issue is somewhat addressed in [this question](http://kiln.stackexchange.com/questions/2947/does-it-make-sense-to-use-named-branches-and-branch-repositories-together), but I'm more interested in finding out how to deal with this using branch repos (and not named branches).

I understand there are ways to modify history (e.g. the [collapse extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/CollapseExtension)) so that the changes get collapsed in the history of the repository, but we'd like to preserve the history.

Looking at the [mercurial](http://selenic.com/repo/hg) and [mozilla](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/) trees, I don't see a clear way to tell where safe revisions are to sync. Is this not as important as we think it is?

Comment: On the Mercurial project itself, we have the guideline "every commit should pass tests". We don't keep to this perfectly, but we do pretty well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need to check out **ANY** old revision and expect it to build?

I agree with you that you should be able to expect that the tip will always build.
This can be easily achieved, [like Lazy Badger already said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7518723/how-do-we-manage-granular-changesets-in-the-central-shared-repository/7545143#7545143), by some kind of "don't push unfinished work to the main repo" policy / mutual agreement.

Concerning older revisions:

- if you want to build older official releases of your software again (like, you're at version 1.6 now and want to make an v1.2 executable), you can expect the `1.2` tag to build as well if everybody always sticked to the "don't push unfinished work" policy.
- if you want to take **ANY** revision and build it...well, do you really need this? Any bugs in previous versions will probably refer to official releases (see the "`1.2` tag" stuff above), and not to something in between.
- if you **really** need a buildable version from in between the official releases (for whatever reason), you'll have to look at the commit messages and find the commit that says `feature 'foo' finished` (and not the one that says `started implementation of feature 'foo'`).
  Yes, this requires a bit of thinking / common sense, but I can't imagine that you will need this really often.

Answer (score 1):

Political solution may be "don't push crap into main repo", isn't it?

Technical solution will be **not tag**, but **one bookmark** ("KnownAsGood"), applied to the last working HEAD of default branch and agreement between devs "Update not to tip, but to bookmark"

Who'll test commits and move bookmark is another question from "project management" tag

Answer (score 1):

If you're using feature branches and merging them without fast forward merges, you still have only stable builds on the mainline, but can see the unstable stuff on the feature branches if desired.

Answer (score 0):

You can always [tag](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Tag) your commits.  These could be major/minor releases, successful builds or however you like. You can see the [mercurial](http://selenic.com/repo/hg/tags) and [mozilla](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/tags) tags in their repos.

Comment: and every tag will add the revision to repository?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that question. You can use tags to mark existing commits as special in some way such as a milestone. If you are using a central repository the tags would be pushed along with the rest of your commits.

Comment: @bialix - yes, add changeset, because each tagging *change versioned file .hgtags*